# Symfony2 KnpLabsGaufrette - Get local filesystem per twig (downloadable files)

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, gaufrette

i'm using this config.yml.

```
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
       uploaded_files:
            local:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads"
                create: true
    filesystems:
        uploaded_files:
            adapter:    uploaded_files
            alias:      uploaded_files
```

Now i want to access uploaded files per twig.
Also for example:

```
<a href="{{ path('gaufrette_download', {system: 'uploaded_files', file: 'test.txt'}) }}>{{ 'Download' | trans }}</a>
```

The file should have a path like...

```
http://localhost/web/uploads/test.txt
```

I want a direct access to the file(s).
No controller (action).

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your folder is web-accessible (i.e. you can type the url `http://localhost/web/uploads/test.txt` in your address bar and download the file), all you have to do is map the route `gaufrette_download` to that path. Your bundle's `routing.yml` could look like this (notice the missing `defaults: { controller: ... }`):

```
gaufrette_download:
    path: /web/uploads/{file}
```

If your `.htaccess` is defined properly your web server should serve the file instead of accessing your application. You might have to add requirements for `file`, e.g. to allow for slashes (search the symfony cookbook for this)

If you just want to skip writing a controller (action), you could just as well [create an event listener which is triggered when your request matches the route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types).

Comment: Thank you. There is no dynamic but i could define one route for one filesystem. Thanks.